# MS-SQL sort output in descending order

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I have this MS-SQL query with thousands of row records in database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 7 DATENAME(MM, mydatetime) + ' ' + CAST(DAY(mydatetime) AS VARCHAR(2)) as thedate
    , MONTH(mydatetime)
    , DAY(mydatetime)
    , COUNT(Page) as totalcount
    , count(DISTINCT Page) as visitors
  FROM someTable
  WHERE Page LIKE '%AEC%'
  GROUP BY DATENAME(MM, mydatetime) + ' ' + CAST(DAY(mydatetime) AS VARCHAR(2))
    , MONTH(mydatetime)
    , DAY(mydatetime)
  ORDER BY MONTH(mydatetime) DESC
    , DAY(mydatetime) DESC
```

It will output this:

```
thedate     | totalcount | visitors
-----------------------------------
October 17  |     4      |    1
October 15  |     1      |    1
October 12  |     1      |    1
October 3   |     3      |    3
October 2   |     42     |    22
September 28|     2      |    1
September 21|     14     |    10
```

My problem is that I simply cant output this in descending order so it will look like this:

```
thedate     | totalcount | visitors
-----------------------------------
September 21|     14     |    10
September 28|     2      |    1
October 2   |     42     |    22
October 3   |     3      |    3
October 12  |     1      |    1
October 15  |     1      |    1
October 17  |     4      |    1
```

So any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your example output appears to me to be in ASCENDING order not DESCENDING order.  ASCENDING goes from earlier to later.  DESCENDING goes from later to earlier.

Comment: What makes you think that your desired output is on descending order?, do you mean ascending order?, in that case, just take out the `DESC`

Comment: If I do that, it will give me first 7 records from database dating like back from last year

Comment: @crashtestxxx - So your actual requirement is different that the one you posted. You need the last 7 records, returned in ascending order

Comment: @Lamak please tell me how it accept order by inside subquey it always gives me error Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your actual requirement, you can use your current query as a derived table and order that result in the way you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT DISTINCT TOP 7 DATENAME(mm, mydatetime) + ' ' 
                              + CAST(DAY(mydatetime) AS VARCHAR(2)) AS thedate, 
                              MONTH(mydatetime)                     AS theMonth, 
                              DAY(mydatetime)                       AS theDay, 
                              COUNT(page)                           AS totalcount, 
                              COUNT(DISTINCT page)                  AS visitors 
        FROM   sometable 
        WHERE  page LIKE '%AEC%' 
        GROUP  BY DATENAME(mm, mydatetime) + ' ' 
                  + CAST(DAY(mydatetime) AS VARCHAR(2)), 
                  MONTH(mydatetime), 
                  DAY(mydatetime) 
        ORDER  BY MONTH(mydatetime) DESC, 
                  DAY(mydatetime) DESC) A
ORDER BY theMonth, theDay
```

Comment: @RThomas - well, I'm hoping that this is what the op actually wants :-)

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed. Sorry if I was not clear with my question.

Comment: @Lamak please tell me how it accept order by inside subquey it always gives me error Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 16 The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `DESC` from your ORDER BY clause.
Your result is in exact reverse order because of DESC!

Comment: I will get last year 7 records from database. i need 7 most current records.

Comment: The ORDER BY clause does not alter the set of records you will get. It only changes the order of the resultant records.
If you aren't getting the right records, it means something is wrong before or including the WHERE clause.

I notice your query has no mention of 'YEAR'? Could that be a problem?

Comment: On second thoughts, you can do a nested select to get the desired result.

`Select * from (select.....//your current query) TableA
ORDER BY month, day;`

Answer (score 0):

To get the order you specify including only the dates you want in the return results you need to remove the desc and add a date filter to your where clause.

That may also allow you to get rid of the top statement if your do your filter right.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 7 DATENAME(MM, mydatetime) 
    + ' ' + CAST(DAY(mydatetime) AS VARCHAR(2)) as thedate
    , MONTH(mydatetime)
    , DAY(mydatetime)
    , COUNT(Page) as totalcount
    , count(DISTINCT Page) as visitors
  FROM someTable
  WHERE Page LIKE '%AEC%' 
    AND /* filter date range i.e. MONTH(mydatetime) > 9 AND YEAR(mydatetime) > 2011 */
  GROUP BY DATENAME(MM, mydatetime) + ' ' + CAST(DAY(mydatetime) AS VARCHAR(2))
    , MONTH(mydatetime)
    , DAY(mydatetime)
  ORDER BY MONTH(mydatetime) 
    , DAY(mydatetime)
```

Comment: Iv tried to use `WHERE mydatetime> GETDATE()-8 AND Page LIKE '%AEC%'`, but it gives me some nonsense data back.

Comment: GETDATE()-8 only goes back 8 days.  Most of the records in your example occur earlier than 8 days ago.

Comment: DATE_ADD Very useful as well. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, just realized Its for MySQL. I get error "it is not recognized built in function" in MS-SQL.

Comment: In that case use DateAdd  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819(v=sql.105).aspx  Not sure why I thought you were using MySQL - I see your question title now.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Definitely something I can use.