# Sort table on descending SQL

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to make a leaderboard for a game that I'm playing.
I've made a website that displays the stats from the game.
I am trying to make the table be able to be sorted by highest to lowest.
But it does the opposite of what I'm trying to do. 
If you have any questions please ask and thanks in advance.

```
        <?php
    // Database output
    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    //Plaatsen voor select option element HTML

    $orderBy = array('Name', 'Kills', 'Deaths', 'KDR');

    $order = 'Name';
    if (isset($_GET['orderBy']) && in_array($_GET['orderBy'], $orderBy)) {
        $order = $_GET['orderBy'];
    }

    $query = 'SELECT Name, Kills, Deaths, KDR FROM GlobalPlayerData ORDER BY '.$order;

    $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    $conn->close();
    ?>
    <table class="table table-striped " >
      <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col"><a href="#">Head</a></th>
        <th scope="col"><a href="?orderBy=Name">Player name</a></th>
        <th scope="col"><a href="?orderBy=Kills">Kills</a></th>
        <th scope="col"><a href="?orderBy=Deaths">Deaths</a></th>
        <th scope"col"><a href="?orderBy=KDR">KDR</a></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  <?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>

  <?php echo '<tr><td>'.'<img src="https://minotar.net/avatar/'.$row1[0].'/50"></td><td>'.$row1[0].'</td><td>'.$row1[1].'</td><td>'.$row1[2].'</td><td>'.$row1[3].'</tr>';?>

  <?php endwhile;?>
  </table>
```

Comment: ASC vs DESC in the order by

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MS-SQL sort output in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961444/ms-sql-sort-output-in-descending-order)

Comment: in your `$query` statement, you simply need to append how you want to ORDER BY. SQL allows you to specify not only the column but also the order. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does `$query` evaluate to?

I see the query here:
`SELECT Name, Kills, Deaths, KDR FROM GlobalPlayerData ORDER BY '.$order`

So say if `Name` is selected - the query will be:
`SELECT Name, Kills, Deaths, KDR FROM GlobalPlayerData ORDER BY Name`

If you aren't specifying an ordering keyword then the default behaviour of `ORDER BY` is ascending order:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-order-by/

You will need to specify `DESC` for descending to make it order from highest to lowest. So your `$query` variable becomes:

`$query = 'SELECT Name, Kills, Deaths, KDR FROM GlobalPlayerData ORDER BY '.$order.' DESC';`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your $query variable to

```
'SELECT Name, Kills, Deaths, KDR FROM GlobalPlayerData ORDER BY ' . $order . ' DESC';
```

The `DESC` will return the results in a descending order, based upon the value of your $order variable.